# Determine the least value that the area of the triangle OAP can take. O is the origin, A is known and P is an unknown point on a line

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have two lines

$$ 
l_1:
\begin{cases}
x=-14-4t\\
y=5+t\\
z=t
\end{cases}
$$

$$ 
l_2:
\begin{cases}
x=t\\
y=2t\\
z=2t
\end{cases}
$$

I have a known point A on $l_2$,

$$
A=(1,2,2)
$$

and an unknown point P on $l_1$, which I want to use to minimize the area of the triangle OAP, where O is the origin. How do I do this? I'm having troubles visualizing this as I tried doing it by finding the shortest distance between the lines to use as the length of one of the sides in the triangle and use the formula for triangles $\frac{b\cdot h}{2}$, but I got the wrong answer. So it must be something else.

Comment: Use area triangle $\text{OAP}=\frac{1}{2}\left|\overset{\rightharpoonup }{\text{OA}} \times  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{\text{OP}}\right|$ where "$\times $" is the cross product

Comment: How would I find P?

Comment: $P(-14-4 t,5+t,t)$ is an arbitrary point on $l_1$. Write the area as a function of $t$ and minimize. Are we allowed to use Calculus?

Comment: Hmm. Not if that entails any derivatives or anything. What did you have in mind?

Comment: Hmm. How about using the shortest distance as the height $PH$. It is not one of the sides.

Comment: Wouldn't it be just that, a side? If it is the height.